# How make faker gem create english sentences and paragraphs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

I use following code in `lib/tasks/sample_data.rake` file to generate fake data to fill development database.

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    Faker::Config.locale = :en
    99.times do |n|
      title  = Faker::Lorem.words(2..10)
      body  = Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(2..8)
      Topic.create!(title: title,
                   body: body)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is the generated text for title looks like this in `index` page

```
--- - doloribus - numquam - placeat - delectus - et - vero
--- - nostrum - numquam - laudantium - voluptas - est - laborum
--- - perferendis - nemo - facilis - quis - eos - quia - sint
```

There are unnecessary hiphens in the generated output, This also happens in the generated paragraphs. As shown below.

```
--- - Fuga explicabo et ea. Excepturi earum ut consequatur minima iure.  
Molestias id tempora alias quisquam animi earum. Eius libero minima ut.  
Repudiandae eum commodi. - Iure aliquam at maxime. Rerum ea non corrupti  
asperiores est. Debitis suscipit nihil quod ut eaque sint repellat.   
quae doloremque. - Voluptatem facere deleniti nisi libero. Molestiae 
magni dolores repudiandae in corporis. Ut enim illum optio et architecto.
```

How do I prevent this behavior of adding unnecessary hyphens, and create clean looking English statements and paragraphs with faker gem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think Faker methods accept range as arguments. In doc it only accepts numbers. Thus I can't even reproduce your problem in console by copying your code.

Maybe you want to generate words or paragraphs in random length? You can use `rand` to generate it. Like this:

```
title = Faker::Lorem.words(number: rand(2..10))
body  = Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(sentence_count: rand(2..8))
```

#### Update

Faker will create **HASH** instead of plain string.

So, for your title, you'd better use `sentence` instead of `words` and then chomp the last `.`

```
title = Faker::Lorem.sentence(word_count: rand(2..10)).chomp('.')
# or
title = Faker::Lorem.words(number: rand(2..10)).join(' ')
```

For body, join the paragraphs with `\n` or whatever you like

```
body  = Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(sentence_count: rand(2..8)).join('\n')
```

##### Update 2

[Positional keywords deprecated in favour of keyword arguments in Faker 2.0 in 2019](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/pull/1698)

[Faker::Lorem reference](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/doc/default/lorem.md)

Comment: Thanks. Most of my expectations are full filled. After looking close at faker, I think I can't get english words as output from Faker::Lorem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

This addresses your secondary question about getting random English words.

There are a few Faker classes that do generate random words in English.

`Faker::Commerce.product_name` will generate some humorous results such as:

- "Awesome Concrete Chair"
- "Fantastic Plastic Hat"
- "Gorgeous Steel Pants"

`Faker::Company.catch_phrase` also generates random English buzzwords like:

- "Multi-lateral intermediate conglomeration"
- "Advanced object-oriented Graphic Interface"
- "Programmable mission-critical analyzer"

I find using these brings a bit of levity to testing.

This is from http://rubydoc.info/github/stympy/faker/master/Faker/.

Comment: It's funny ;) Any other methods like this? I can't find documentation of Faker on the web.

Comment: @Myoung Hoon Kim: I've added a link to the page where I found this information.

Comment: For generating a paragraph, try this (in rails console):  `a = ""`, then `50.times do a = a + Faker::ChuckNorris.fact end`. Have fun :D